# Rock, Paper, Scissors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

Alrighty, it's that time of week again where I am officially throwing my hands up in the air with MATLAB and asking for help. My goal this week is to try and make a function that takes in two inputs, which are strings that say 'Rock, Paper, Scissors' (or whatever the choices are), it then outputs one of three strings 'Player 1 Wins!', 'Player 2 Wins!' or 'Keep Playing!'. To win, the player must beat the other two out of three times (a tie counts as a loss for both players)

```
function[winner] = RockPaperScissors(player1, player2)
[move1, others] = strtok(player1, ',');
[move2, rest] = strtok(others, ',');
[move3, ~] = strtok(rest, ',');

[go1, others] = strtok(player2, ',');
[go2, rest] = strtok(others, ',');
[go3, ~] = strtok(rest, ',');

Counter1 = 0;
Counter2 = 0;

for i = 1:3
if strcmp(move1, 'Rock') && strcmp(go1, 'Paper')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Rock') && strcmp(go1, 'Scissors')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Rock') && strcmp(go1, 'Rock')
    Counter1 = 0;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Paper') && strcmp(go1, 'Paper')
    Counter1 = 0;   
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Paper') && strcmp(go1, 'Rock')
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Paper') && strcmp(go1, 'Scissors')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go1, 'Scissors')
    Counter1 = 0;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go1, 'Paper')
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move1, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go1, 'Rock')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
end
if strcmp(move2, 'Rock') && strcmp(go2, 'Paper')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Rock') && strcmp(go2, 'Scissors')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Rock') && strcmp(go2, 'Rock')
    Counter1 = 0;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Paper') && strcmp(go2, 'Paper')
    Counter1 = 0;   
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Paper') && strcmp(go2, 'Rock')
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Paper') && strcmp(go2, 'Scissors')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go2, 'Scissors')
    Counter1 = 0;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go2, 'Paper')
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move2, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go2, 'Rock')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
end
if strcmp(move3, 'Rock') && strcmp(go3, 'Paper')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Rock') && strcmp(go3, 'Scissors')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Rock') && strcmp(go3, 'Rock')
    Counter1 = 0;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Paper') && strcmp(go3, 'Paper')
    Counter1 = 0;   
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Paper') && strcmp(go3, 'Rock')
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Paper') && strcmp(go3, 'Scissors')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go3, 'Scissors')
    Counter1 = 0;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go3, 'Paper')
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif strcmp(move3, 'Scissors') && strcmp(go3, 'Rock')
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
end

if max(Counter1, Counter2) == Counter2
    winner = 'Player 2 Wins!';
elseif max(Counter1, Counter2) == Counter1
    winner = 'Player 1 Wins!';
elseif max(Counter1, Counter2) ~= (Counter1 || Counter2) % I tried making a Counter 3, did not work out
    winner = 'Keep Playing!';
end

end
```

As you can see, I have most of this bad boy running. My issue now is that when I run the test case '        [winner1] = rockPaperScissors('Rock,Scissors,Scissors','Paper,Rock,Scissors')
It outputs my answer in a vertical 'ans' and not as winner. Additionally, it gives me 'Player 2 Win!' even though it should be a tie. I tried debugging it all, but can't figure out where my issue is. Bah!

Comment: I can use commas, just not sure if it's giving me quite what I want it to. I tried to use & to do what I wanted, but that didn't work. And by do what I wanted, I mean compare the two strings (or record the outcome at least).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you actually thought about using a [**`table`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/table.html)? It's perfect for your purpose!

Just an idea, how to do it alternatively. Please don't nail me on the fact, that I haven't considered all your restrictions and conditions, but it should be easy for you to adapt my function how you like it.

```
function RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock(player1, player2, rounds)

%// creating the table with all combinations
header = {'Rock';'Paper';'Scissors';'Lizard';'Spock'};
Rock = [0;-1;1;1;-1];
Paper = [1;0;-1;-1;1];
Scissors = [-1;1;0;1;-1];
Lizard = [-1;1;-1;0;1];
Spock = [1;-1;1;-1;0];
T = table(Rock,Paper,Scissors,Lizard,Spock,'RowNames',header);


%// play and display winners of every round
points = 0;
for ii = 1:rounds

   pointsRound  =  T{player1(ii), player2(ii)};   %// no need for if-conditions
                                                  %// one line is enough
   points = points + pointsRound;

   if     pointsRound > 0;  disp(['Player 1 wins round ' num2str(ii) '!'])
   elseif pointsRound < 0;  disp(['Player 2 wins round ' num2str(ii) '!'])
   else                     disp(['Draw in round ' num2str(ii) '!'])
   end

end

%// display overall winner
if     points >  rounds/2; disp('Player 1 Wins!')
elseif points == 0;        disp(['Draw!' num2str(ii) '!'])
else                       disp('Player 2 Wins!')

end
```

and now lets play:

```
player1 = {'Rock','Scissors','Scissors'}
player2 = {'Paper','Rock','Scissors'}

RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock(player1, player2, 3)
```

returns:

```
Player 1 wins round 1!
Player 1 wins round 2!
Tie in round 3!
Player 1 Wins!
```

---

you can also implement some advanced features, for example give names to the players:

```
function RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock(player1, player2, rounds)

plname = inputname(1);
p2name = inputname(2);

...

   if     pointsRound > 0;  disp([plname ' wins round ' num2str(ii) '!'])

...

else                disp([p2name ' Wins!'])

end
```

and

```
Sheldon = {'Spock','Spock','Spock'}
Penny = {'Paper','Rock','Scissors'}

RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock(sheldon, penny, 3)
```

yields

```
Sheldon wins round 1!
Penny wins round 2!
Penny wins round 3!
Penny Wins!
```

---

If you insist on your string input with commas:

```
Sheldon = 'Spock,Spock,Spock'
Penny = 'Paper,Rock,Scissors'
```

you need to add [**`strsplit`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to the function:

```
player1= strsplit(player1,',')
player2= strsplit(player2,',')
```

Comment: Not sure if gaming theme or female OP attracting such high quality answers.

Comment: I technically have to use what strings they give me, so strings with commas it is. Now making a table does make some sense, but that doesn't quite work for what I need to do. And I'm not too sure how to make it work.

Comment: I haven't learned about tables quite yet either, so I'm not comfortable using that idea

Comment: @Jigg - I think it's both... besides which, the problems that the OP have posted are a bit challenging and fun to solve.  I've also  answered two of her questions :)

Comment: +1 - Love your [Big Bang Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory) references :)... Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock - SHOOT!

Comment: @Jigg actually neither the one nor the other. But I intended to answer the question including Spock and needed to have a look at [**wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock) for the relations, and there came up the normal table and the fact that solving it with if conditions is overkill. ;)

Comment: @JessicaMarie the strings are no problem, just use the very end of my answer: `strsplit` and then you can use the function as intended. And to be honest, it was the first time I used tables as well (there are quite new in Matlab) - but as you want to get a value based on two strings, a table just seems perfect: you have a row and a column and at the crossing point it says who wins.

Comment: I had to overkill it with conditionals :P But I figured it out. I have about 80 lines of code, but it works. Irregardless, I'm sure your code works perfectly :) I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the function `strcmp` instead of the `==` operator. The inputs are char arrays, which is why `==` is complaining about the dimensions.

Here's an example for your first `if` statement:

```
if strcmp(move1, 'Rock') && strcmp(go1, 'Paper')
    winner1 = 'Player 2 Wins!';
```

Here I've made 2 changes, the first is to use strcmp, and the second to use scalar AND i.e. `&&`

See `help strcmp` and help `&&` for more details.

Comment: Would I have to define what beats what beneath it or above it? Like I need to be like move1 == 'Rock' or move2 == 'Paper' etc strcmp won't give me that. I wouldn't be able to tell them what would win

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you more details of what I mean.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. Thanks :)